# How do I exclude specific file names from an MS DOS dir list?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am creating an MS DOS batch script that needs to list every .bat file in the current directory, but not show `autoexec.bat` or other utilities or systems .bat files that shouldn't be run by the user.

I currently have `DIR "*.bat" /B /P`

This lists all .bat files appropriately, but it shows autoexec.bat.  How would I exclude that from the list?  Also slightly important, how could I chop off the file extensions and show more than the 7-characters DOS limits files to?

Constraints: I am not able to use a DOS version above WinME.  That is the version I am using.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
There is plenty of information on the internet about doing this, but it is all in the windows command processor, **not** MS DOS.  Please understand that DOS and the Command Prompt are not the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Add more names separated with slashes here:
set exclude=/autoexec/
for %%a in (*.bat) do (
   if "!exclude:/%%~Na/=!" equ "%exclude%" (
      echo %%~Na
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

Batch file processing is slow, so you should use techniques that allows a Batch file to run faster. For example:

- Try to use the minimum lines/commands to achieve a certain result. Try to avoid external commands (*.exe files) like `find`, `findstr`, `fc`, etc. specially if they work on small amounts of data; use `if` command instead.
- Use `for %%a in (*.bat)...` instead of `for /F %%a in ('dir /B *.bat')...`. The second method requires to execute cmd.exe and store its output in a file before `for` command can process its lines.
- Avoid pipes and use redirections instead. A pipe require the execution of two copies of cmd.exe to process the command at each side of the pipe.
- A simple way to check if a variable contain a given string is trying to delete the string from the variable: if the result is *different* then the string exists in the variable: `if "!variable:%string%=!" neq "%variable%" echo The string is in the variable`.
- Previous method may also be used to check if a variable have anyone of a list of values: `set list=one two three`, `if "!list:%variable%=!" neq "%list%" echo The variable have one value from the list`. If the values of the list may have spaces, they must be separated by another delimiter.

**EDIT**: *New version added as answer to new comments*

The easiest way to pause one page at a time is to use `more` filter this way:

```
theBatchFile | more
```

However, the program must reorder the output in order to show it in columns. The new version below achieve both things, so it does not require `more` filter; you just need to set the desired number of columns and rows per page.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Add more names separated with slashes here:
set exclude=/autoexec/
rem Set the first two next variables as desired:
set /A columns=5, rows=41,   wide=(80-columns)/columns, col=0, row=0
rem Create filling spaces to align columns
set spaces=
for /L %%a in (1,1,%wide%) do set spaces= !spaces!
set line=
for %%a in (*.bat) do (
   if "!exclude:/%%~Na/=!" equ "%exclude%" (
      rem If this column is less than the limit...
      set /A col+=1
      if !col! lss %columns% (
         rem ... add it to current line
         set name=%%~Na%spaces%
         set "line=!line!!name:~0,%wide%! "
      ) else (
         rem ... show current line and reset it
         set name=%%~Na
         echo !line!!name:~0,%wide%!
         set line=
         set /a col=0, row+=1
         rem If this row is equal to the limit...
         if !row! equ %rows% (
            rem ...do a pause and reset row
            pause
            set row=0
         )
      )
   )
)
rem Show last line, if any
if defined line echo %line%
```

Antonio

Comment: Please add some information and explanation that will be beneficial to the OP and other people having similar problems. As of right now, this answer only stands as a block of code that might *fix* the solution to a localized issue, but not for future, similar issues.

Comment: I am unable to test your code right now, but it looks promising!  I will approve your answer as soon as I can confirm it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I must also mention, this is in DOS version Windows Millennium.  There is no CMD.exe.  There is only internal commands (Command.com) which I assume is similar to CMD.exe.

Comment: Alright!  This code is almost there.  I need one more thing, I want to display this one page at a time, allowing the user to press any key until it has all shown.  Even better would be if I could get it into columns as well as pages.  I want to make sure it is all shown and in as few pages as possible.

Comment: This program works amazing on windows, but I get "Bad Command or File Name" on dos repeated over and over again.  And syntax errors for `set name=%%~Na`.  I think I am going to have to figure out some way to get a newer DOS platform.  XP maybe.  Anyway, I appreciate your help, and your solution theoretically should work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
attrib +h autoexec.bat
```

should hide autoexec.bat and it should thus not appear in the list

Comment: This did not work.  I still get exactly the same results as if I had not added the code.  This is also visible when using the windows console to test it.

Comment: It works for me. Just needing a way to easily exclude 1 file from processing. Like this way to exclude files, perfect for little amount of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
DIR "*.bat" /B /P | find /v "autoexec" | for %i in (*.bat) do @echo %~ni
```

Comment: Little problem here, I can't find the "find.exe" utility for my ME DOS installation.  I have found a plethora of incorrect versions however.

Comment: Unless you have seriously damaged your OS, FIND.EXE is a MS-DOS system command http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands and it should be in the Windows System32 directory, e.g.: C:\Windows\System32 if you cannot find it, may be you should repair your OS installation

Comment: MS DOS doesn't have Find.exe built in.  It is an external program and completely optional.  As it appears, using find.exe became no longer needed because other code could do exactly what it could.  Regardless, it is no longer included with the DOS ME boot disks, even those with all utilities.  In more modern dos installations, loads of those old programs are nowhere to be found.

Comment: This one theoretically is the the most compact and simplest.  But it can be better - you.  Unfortunately for OP this won't work, because of DOS - but `dir *.bat|find /v "autoexec"`.  you don't need the the additional loop - not sure why you'd want it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` to process each file name individually:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir "*.bat" /b') do (
  set system=0
  if "%%i"=="autoexec.bat" set system=1
  if "%%i"=="somesystem.bat" set system=1
  if !system!==0 echo %%i
)
```

Another method without variables:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir "*.bat" /b') do call :test %%i
goto continue
  :test
  if "%1"=="autoexec.bat" goto :eof
  if "%1"=="somesystem.bat" goto :eof
  echo %1
  goto :eof
:continue
```

For both, you can add new filenames to exclude from the list.

Comment: This prints out all of the batch text for every file in the folder, along with the first file name. Definitely not working.