# How to delete all files in a folder except 5 files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I would like to create a batch script in Windows to delete all files from a folder except for 5 specific files. For example, I would like to delete all *.txt files except for file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt and file5.txt.

Comment: I would rename those 5 files (to a different extension), delete *.txt, then rename them back.

Comment: @joshpoley That may work in another situation, but he wants to delete all files.

Comment: Actually, I see now that the OP says he wants to delete both all files, and then just *.txt

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code but does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following command and it works. The test1.txt and test2.txt is the file im excluding for deleting. What it does is define the exclusion file in / and loop through the txt files inside the folder. This is to ensure it targets only the .txt files.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Add more names separated with slashes here:
set exclude=/test1.txt/test2.txt/
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   if "!exclude:/%%~a/=!" equ "%exclude%" (
      echo "Deleting" %%~a  
      del "%%~a"
   )
)
```

The codes are adapted from this thread - [How do I exclude specific file names from an MS DOS dir list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714363/how-do-i-exclude-specific-file-names-from-an-ms-dos-dir-list). I just modified a little bit to display the file extension(required for delete command) and the delete action.

Comment: This piece of code works perfectly!  exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b ^|findstr /xirv "file[1-5]\.txt"') do del "%%~a"
```

Comment: But the question said, “For example, … except for file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt and file5.txt.” Those names may be only an example; the real names may be `mercury.txt`, `venus.txt`, `earth.txt`, `mars.txt`, etc., and this answer is not easily adaptable to that more realistic (worldly!) scenario. On the up side, this solution is trivially modified to include hidden files.

Comment: @Scott my code is only an example for the power of Regex in the Windows Command Shell Scripting Language. If you like, put `pluto.url` and `blue.navi` in the expression. I'm _not_ able to write a script solving all scripting problems in the world :/

Comment: My point is that you posted a neat hack that depends on the file names being the same except for one character. Yes, of course you could change your answer to use `"pluto.url blue.navi"`; it just wouldn’t be as neat.

Comment: @Scott that's _scripting_, it always depends on conditions and properties of distinct programming surroundings.

Answer (score 2):

This will work - don't run it in any folder other than the one you intend:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do attrib +h "file%%a.txt"
del *.*?
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do attrib -h "file%%a.txt"
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Why do you use `*.*?` instead of `*.*`?

Comment: @scott It stops del from asking if you really want to delete all files.  There is a switch in modern versions of DEL to do the same thing.

Comment: But `*.*?` won't match files without an extension, right?

Answer (score 2):

Delete all *.txt files in folder **SCANDIR** except, file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt

```
@echo off
@break off
@title How to delete all files in a folder except 5 files - D3F4ULT
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "SCANDIR=D:\Batch\Stack Overflow\How to delete all files in a folder except 5 files\files"

if not exist "!SCANDIR!\" echo ERROR&&echo.&&echo Folder not found = '%~nx1'&&echo.&&echo Exiting...&&echo.&&ping -n 8 localhost>nul&&exit /B 1

for %%a in ( "!SCANDIR!\*.txt" ) do (
  set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=Y"
  if /I "%%~nxa" EQU "file1.txt" set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=N"
  if /I "%%~nxa" EQU "file2.txt" set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=N"
  if /I "%%~nxa" EQU "file3.txt" set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=N"
  if /I "%%~nxa" EQU "file4.txt" set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=N"
  if /I "%%~nxa" EQU "file5.txt" set "DEL_FILE_FLAG=N"
  if defined DEL_FILE_FLAG if "!DEL_FILE_FLAG!" EQU "Y" (
    del /f /q "%%~dpnxa">nul 2>&1
  )
)

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
md _emptyDir_ & robocopy _emptyDir_ . /purge /xf file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

This will create a new directory (`_emptyDir_`) with no files in it. Then robocopy is used to purge the current directory of files not present in `_emptyDir_`. As there are no files in the directory, all files get deleted except the files indicated to be excluded. Aditionaly, there is no need to `rmdir _emptyDir_`, as robocopy will also handle it.

To use this method to only delete the txt files from directory, keeping the indicated files, the syntax will be

```
md _emptyDir_ & robocopy _emptyDir_ . *.txt /purge /xf file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

From empty directory to current directory, process only *.txt files, deleting all not existing in source (there is anything on it) except the excluded files.

In this case, as only txt files are processed, `_emptyDir_` is not removed automatically.

Answer (score -2):

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    if not %%f == file1.txt if not %%f == file2.txt if not %%f == file3.txt if not %%f == file4.txt if not %%f == file5.txt del %%f
)
```

If you don’t like ridiculously long command lines, do

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
        if not %%f == file1.txt (
                if not %%f == file2.txt (
                        if not %%f == file3.txt (
                                if not %%f == file4.txt (
                                        if not %%f == file5.txt (
                                                del %%f
        )))))
)
```

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this?  It doesn't delete all files, and doesn't handle long filenames, but it should work fine with the filenames given.  Maybe there is one too many `)` characters in the lower code but why downvote and give no feedback?

Comment: This command is not recommended even longer, and there is a much more elegant logic to simulate an OR command batch. See my answer to better understand it I use a technique for implementing the logical OR in batch, using the variable "DEL_FILE_FLAG".

Comment: @D3F4ULT: Yes, your technique for implementing/simulating an OR by using a flag is elegant, and clearly is extendable to larger numbers of excluded files. But what do you mean by “This command is not recommended even longer”?

Comment: Command... i mean that it is not recommended to use several ifs so that way, besides being ugly, bad for maintenance. Even with batch script, I always try to create the codes more gracefully, I see too many that minimize the code to get it working, I already like to make a functional, beautiful and compatible code whenever possible with checks and checks for debugging and find errors and make handling errors, but this is due to the fact of using batch all day then I'm addicted xD